# Excel VBA - "for loop" for unconnected cells

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

My purpose is to run a macro automatically on some 20 cells across my active worksheet whenever these are edited. Instead of having the same macro in place for every cell individually (makes the code very long and clumsy), I want to create a for loop which goes something like this:

```
for i="A10","A21","C3" ... etc
if target.address = "i" then
'execute macro
end if
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this... maybe another way would be a better option?

I'd really appreciate your help in the matter - thank you very much indeed.

Comment: I think You will find [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317029/need-help-making-the-vba-excel-code-better/16317480#16317480) very useful in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event. Below is sample code. You need to put the code on the sheet code section

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:B5")
' If there is change in this range

    If Not Intersect(rng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Target.Address & " range is edited"
        ' you can do manipulation here
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh, thank you for this. How would I select a range of unconnected values, i.e. A10, A25, C43, etc as the range, without having to repeat the macro for each of them separately?

Comment: For multiple range you can use this.  `Set rng = Range("A10, A25, C43")`  as per your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to capture the edits. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx.

The event body receives a `Range` object that represents the modified cells. You can then use `Application.Intersect` to determine if one of your target cells is in the modified range.